# Spring 4 lazy-init not honoured for org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter?

Tags: lazy-loading, spring-jms

I'm trying to convert a Spring 3 app to Spring 4 (4.3.2.RELEASE) but I can't get org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter to lazy load anymore.
To isolate the problem I removed all references to the following bean def but it still tries to load and throws a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/MessageListener, which is a runtime dependency that I am not providing on purpose in this setup:

```
<bean id="messageListener" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter" lazy-init="true" scope="prototype">
    <property name="defaultListenerMethod" value="handleRequest"/>
    <property name="defaultResponseDestination" ref="defaultResponseDestination" />
    <property name="delegate" ref="stringRequestToStreamRequestHandler" />
</bean>
```

Is this expected behaviour or a bug?